# For half-hourly intervals can I use Pandas TimeDeltaIndex, PeriodIndex or DateTimeIndex?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, intervals

I have a table of data values that should be indexed with half-hourly intervals, and I've been processing them with Pandas and Numpy. Currently they're in CSV files and I import them using `read_csv` to a dataframe with only the interval-endpoint as an index. I am uncomfortable with that and want to have the intervals themselves as the index.

I do not know whether to use a `DateTimeIndex`, a `PeriodIndex` or a `TimedeltaIndex`... All of them seem very similar in practice, to me. My operations include

- Looking up a particular interval
- Checking if a DateTime is contained in a particular interval
- Intersection and (Set)Difference of intervals
- Split and join intervals

Can Pandas even do all of these? Is it advisable? I already am using [this interval library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interval/1.0.0), would using Pandas `tslib` and `period` be better?

Answer (score 0):

if you only need a series with time interval of 30 minutes you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

today = dt.datetime.date()
yesterday = dt.datetime.date()-dt.timedelta(days=1)
time_range = pd.date_range(yesterday,today, freq='30T')
```

now you could use it to set an index such has

```
pd.DataFrame(0, index=time_range,columns=['yourcol'])

Out[35]: 
                     yourcol
2016-09-25 00:00:00        0
2016-09-25 00:30:00        0
2016-09-25 01:00:00        0
2016-09-25 01:30:00        0
2016-09-25 02:00:00        0
```

this would be a DateTimeIndex

you can read more about time interval in pandas here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: But is it an interval in the sense that I can do operations (as described in the question) on? Like intersection and set difference? Does each individual interval have an identity, such that I can find it's start and end point?